# How to run a Ruby script every hour on the hour

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find out how to run a ruby script(method) every hour on the hour and to have it quit upon key pressed.  I have been trying to loop but it seems to run many times during the same second.

Answer (score 4):

Try Ruby [Whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.

Answer (score 3):

The function you want is sleep

A better idea might be to have your script complete rather than loop, and write its output to a file you can check later rather than pressing a key to close.  Then launch the script hourly using [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a few things to consider, you'll have to sleep and you'll have to accept a keypress immediately to stop.  So you'll probably want two threads, one that loops looking for key presses and the other than sleeps and actually performs the action every hour.

I'm a bit of a ruby n00b, so that's what you need conceptually (two threads, one using sleep) but if you need implementation details I'll have to do some research.

Answer (score 0):

Please used [Daemons](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/) gem.